# Is there any way to view the code that V8 generates?

Tags: javascript

I'm working on a very performance critical part of a browser game and was just splitting apart a big pile of code into more manageable chunks but it seems that I'm paying a pretty serious (~40% in total) performance loss for these extra function calls.

At first I figured that V8 just doesn't do inlining upon compilation but then I tried out this little test:

```
const nn = 1000000000;
(()=>{
    var t = Date.now();
    var total = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
        total += i;
    }
    console.log(total, Date.now() - t);
})();
    
(()=>{
    var t = Date.now();
    var total = 0;
    function useless() {}
    for (var i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
        total += i;
        useless();useless();useless();
    }
    console.log(total, Date.now() - t);
})();

(new class {
    useless() {}
    
    test() {
        var t = Date.now();
        var total = 0;
        for (var i = 0; i < nn; i++) {
            total += i;
            this.useless();this.useless();this.useless();
        }
        console.log(total, Date.now() - t);
    }
}).test();
```

And in each case, I get an identical result, useless function calls or not. That tells me that there is practically no cost for a useless function call.

Yet in my real code, adding useless function calls incurs a very real penalty for each added, for example in

```
add_expected_length(v) {
    this.set_block_raw();  // <- this is the useless one
    while (v > 127) { this.buffer.push((v & 127) + 128); v = Math.trunc(v / 128); }
    this.buffer.push(v);
}
```

even if set_block_raw method is empty, adding it there makes the whole algorithm 5% slower, add two in a row and its 7%, three is 9% and on and on, it seems to scale almost linearly with each useless call added I get a 1-2% performance decrease.

Now if I break my class apart and start examining individual calls, isolating pieces of code here and there the problem goes away, the useless call is ignored but trying to figure out what is wrong in this huge inter-dependent algorithm like that would just take forever.

This seems very bizarre to me and I really want to dig into what V8 generates to see what is causing this. Is there a way to peer behind the js and see what chrome and V8 actually does with it?

Comment: One possible reason is that when you call a function thousands of times v8 will optimize it down to the most optimal byte code, while calling something a few times it won't be optimized and will be interpreted each time. It is strange that when the function is empty it still causes this.

Comment: I realize my comment is somewhat tangential to the specific question at hand, but you can get notable performance improvement in your real code if you use Typed Arrays, in addition to some bit twiddling rather than division. Specifically, `while (v > 127 ) { this.buffer[ this.bufferLength++ ] = ( v & 127 ) | 128; v = v >>> 7; }  this.buffer[ this.bufferLength++ ] = v;` where `this.buffer` is a pre-allocated Uint32Array and `this.bufferLength` tracks the next available element in the array...